# Background worker report progress position

Tags: c#, winforms

What is the best position to ReportProgress??

```
//Do my hard work before report progress
bkWorker.ReportProgress((int)percent, company.CompanyName);
```

or

```
bkWorker.ReportProgress((int)percent, company.CompanyName);
//Do my hard work after report progress
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a timing perspective, this shouldn't matter as top or bottom of the loop will happen so quickly.

Just make sure that you cover the edge cases (0% being set from the beginning and 100% being set when done. Your options are below:

```
while(condition)
{
    report
    dowork
}
report 100%
```

OR

```
report 0%
while(condition)
{
    dowork
    report
}
```

OR

```
while(true)
{
    report
    if(100%)
        break;
    dowork
}
```

So, it comes down to your preference in how the logic will look. Processing time will not matter

Comment: Or put another way - you should probably report the work that you have *done*, rather than the work that you are about to do. +1